# How to make add button adds data to datagridview using Stored Procedure C#

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, datagridview

[This is my **PhonebookSystem UI.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crn1q.jpg)

These are my codes for my PhonebookSystem.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            txtLastName.Text = DGPhonebook.CurrentRow.Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString();
            txtFirstName.Text = DGPhonebook.CurrentRow.Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString();
            txtMiddleName.Text = DGPhonebook.CurrentRow.Cells["MiddleName"].Value.ToString();
            txtAge.Text = DGPhonebook.CurrentRow.Cells["Age"].Value.ToString();
            txtEmailAddress.Text = DGPhonebook.CurrentRow.Cells["EmailAddress"].Value.ToString();
            txtContactNo.Text = DGPhonebook.CurrentRow.Cells["ContactNo"].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person p = new Person
            {
                LastName = txtLastName.Text,
                FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
                Middlename = txtMiddleName.Text,
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text),
                EmailAddress = txtEmailAddress.Text,
                ContactNo = txtContactNo.Text
            };

            clsPerson.InsertPerson(p);
        }

        private void DGPhonebook_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DGPhonebook.Rows.Add("1", "XX");
        }
```

These are my clsPerson codes.

```
public static void InsertPerson(Person p)
        {
            PhonebookSQLDataContext db = new PhonebookSQLDataContext();
            db.usp_InsertPerson(p.LastName, p.FirstName, p.Middlename, p.Age, p.EmailAddress, p.ContactNo);
        }
        public static void UpdatePerson(Person p)
        {
            PhonebookSQLDataContext db = new PhonebookSQLDataContext();
            db.usp_UpdatePerson(p.Numbering, p.LastName, p.FirstName, p.Middlename, p.Age, p.EmailAddress, p.ContactNo);
        }
        public static void DeletePerson(Person p)
        {
            PhonebookSQLDataContext db = new PhonebookSQLDataContext();
            db.usp_DeletePerson(p.Numbering);
        }

        public static List<usp_RetrievePersonResult> RetrievePerson = new List<usp_RetrievePersonResult>();

            PhonebookSQLDataContext db = new PhonebookSQLDataContext();
        }
```

I'm having a trouble adding data to datagridview using stored procedure by clicking the add button. Please help.. Thankssss ;)

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Comment: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.

The statement has been terminated.**

Comment: Shouldn't you be following MVP instead of MVC since this is Win Forms app. Back to your error, this error indicates that you are trying to store a longer data than a database column can accept.

Comment: **IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), lastName, firstName, middlename, age, emailAddress, contactNo);**

This is the code error.

Comment: MVC works. My colleagues and professor do MVC

Comment: This is my database table:
**Create Table Person
(
Numbering bigint Primary Key Identity (1,1),
LastName Varchar (50) Not Null,
FirstName Varchar (50) Not Null,
Middlename Varchar (50) Not Null,
Age int,
EmailAddress nVarchar (50),
ContactNo nVarchar not NULL,
)**

I would say it's not longer data than it can accept.  I did input 10 characters only so it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: can u provide sample input data?

Comment: For example:
I want the data in the textboxes to be put in the datagridview.
Those are LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Age, EmailAddress, and ContactNo. These are the column as well.

Comment: If you are using any relational database server like SQL Server then use the query analyzer to insert a sample data through sql query and I am sure you will find your mistake

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014. All I have is this and the stored procedure.

**Create Table Person
(
Numbering bigint Primary Key Identity (1,1),
LastName Varchar (50) Not Null,
FirstName Varchar (50) Not Null,
Middlename Varchar (50) Not Null,
Age int,
EmailAddress nVarchar (50),
ContactNo nVarchar not NULL,
)**

Comment: i'm looking for the solution that makes me transfer my textbox data to datagridview when i press the add button. And I don't use datasource or any sqlconnection command. we're using LINQ to SQL Classes

Answer (score 1):

Its may use for you. I took only name for example.

```
public void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person p = new Person
    {
        nbame = txt1.Text.ToString()
    };
    InsertPerson(p);
    Loadgrid();
}
public void InsertPerson(Person p)
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    Persontbl per = new Persontbl();
    per.name = p.nbame;
    db.Persontbls.InsertOnSubmit(per);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
public void Loadgrid()
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var result = from res in db.Persontbls select name;
    GRD1.DataSource = result;
    GRD1.DataBind();
}
```

Table :

```
 create table Persontbl(name varchar(20 )  primary key)
```